# PHP POST data and retrieve response with curl

Tags: php, post, curl, http-response-codes

I have read many articles and discussions (also in Stackoverflow) but I haven't found a solution.
I have a form with an action to an external web site.

I need to submit my form getting the response of that site (the response header of my http request is good). Is it possible?

I have tried with curl (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER true) but maybe there is something wrong in my following code:

```
        $post_data['xx'] = 'xxx';
        $post_data['yy'] = 'yyy';
        $post_data['zz'] = '13-12-2015';

        $postData = '';
        foreach($post_data as $k => $v) 
        { 
          $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
        }
        rtrim($postData, '&');

        $url = 'http://......';

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result = curl_exec ($ch);          
        $http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        echo $http;

        curl_close ($ch);
```

The return is "0".

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  `var_dump($http)`?

Comment: I have 0 as response from $http. Any ideas. I have tried with var_dump but I receive "int 0". @Devon

Comment: Run `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` to get more information that may help you solve your problem.

Comment: @Emil I have already tried it but it returns an array with the information of my request..

Comment: `I have already tried it but it returns an array with the information of my request` - What a strange coincidence, I wonder if providing that info **by adding it to the question** might be why @Emil asked you to do that. Amaze.

Comment: @Gio if the http code is 0, it usually means the connection failed.

Comment: @AD7six the return includes all the information of my request:
Array ( [url] => https://... [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.031 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.016 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 ....)

Comment: @Devon how can I check it?
Thanks

Comment: @AD7six here you are the information...

Comment: @AD7six thanks for your help.. the problem is about SSL certificate, solved with "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);"

Answer (score 0):

If i picked up what you are looking for ,let me suppose this solution:

**Main.php**

```
<form method=post action=target.php><input name=mypostdata type=text ><input type=submit ></form><?php`include("curl.php");?>
```

**Target.php**

```
<?php if( isset($_POST['mypostdata']) ){echo "<span>done</span>";}else{}?>
```

**curl.php**

```
<?php function file_get_contents_curl($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
  }
$html = file_get_contents_curl("target.php");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span');
//get and display what you need:
$response = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $response;
 ?>
```